# OKHTTP post special character encoding header

Tags: android, okhttp

When the piece of code below is run, no response is received from the server.  On  php side the following was header line was added. header("Content-Type: text/json; Charset=UTF-8");. Before post method ran successfully but now with this header content type no response from server is received. This line was added to the request           .addHeader("Content-Type","text/json; Charset=UTF-8")
but still no result. Is the header assigned correctly ? and also can okhttp call accept special character. A help is most welcome.

```
RequestBody body = new FormEncodingBuilder()  
                    .add("visitor",MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("acc_type").toLowerCase())
                    .add("id_customer",MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("id_customer"))
                    .add("sector",sector)
                    .add("search_who_what",MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("quiQuoi"))
                    .add("search_location",str_ou)
                    .add("agenda",MyApplication.pref.GetPreferences("agenda_envelop"))
                    .add("sort_by", "")
                    .add("advanced_agenda","")
                    .add("distance", "")
                    .build();


public String post(String url, RequestBody body) {



        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Content-Type","text/json; Charset=UTF-8")
        .post(body)
        .build();

        String str_response="";

        Response response;

        try {

            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            try {

                str_response = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("POST_BODY_RESPONSE: "+" url "+url+" strresp "+str_response);

            } catch (Exception ex){

                Log.e("POST_BODY_RESPONSE: ",url+" resp "+str_response);
            }

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            str_response = "";

        }catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            str_response = "";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            str_response = "";
        }

        return str_response;
    }













**Error Log:


04-30 15:06:06.518: W/System.err(5295): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple charsets: text/json; Charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8
04-30 15:06:06.518: W/System.err(5295):     at com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:64)
04-30 15:06:06.518: W/System.err(5295):     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$RealResponseBody.contentType(Call.java:252)
04-30 15:06:06.518: W/System.err(5295):     at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.charset(ResponseBody.java:86)
04-30 15:06:06.518: W/System.err(5295):     at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:82)
04-30 15:06:06.528: W/System.err(5295):     at android.app.utils.OkHttp.post(OkHttp.java:78)
04-30 15:06:06.528: W/System.err(5295):     at android.app.fragment.RechercheResult$2.run(RechercheResult.java:306)
04-30 15:06:06.538: W/System.err(5295):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)**
```

Comment: I think it should be `application/json` instead of `text/json` Also check that your all parameters should be correct.

Comment: still no response and params are correctly set

Comment: Have you set php side too?

Comment: i have no access on php side and php developper is off today

Comment: Oh. Then you need to set at php side too otherwise it will not work.

Comment: ok thanks you will inform you asap